# Best Way to Restric Owl Carousel Height

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using owl carousel as an items:1, slider, and want to restrict the height so it isn't constantly resizing when some images are portrait and landscape, but i'm afraid to use css3 `height:85vh` because it doesn't work on all browsers. Is there a native way to restrict the height via owl carousel options or should i use a css fallback like `item img{max-height:600px;max-height:85vh}`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, both Owl Carousel 1 & 2 have no native options for fixed/restricted height as some other carousel plugins do.

The solution is quite simple, as you have mentioned, you should apply CSS to the classes needed to achieve your affect. If you are worried about your height:85vh not working cross-browser, you could always incorporate a JS backup, like so:

```
$(document).ready(restrictHeight);
$(window).resize(restrictHeight);

function restrictHeight() {
  $('.item img').css('max-height',$(window).outerHeight*0.85);
}
```